# Problem with Dummit's Article on Solving Solvable Quintics

Tags: quintics

"

$(7)\space\space\space[x^2 + (T_1 + T_2\Delta)x+(T_3+T_4\Delta)][x^2 + (T_1 - T_2\Delta)x+(T_3-T_4\Delta)]$
$(8.0)\space\space\space l_0 = (a_0 + a_1\theta + a_2\theta^{2} + a_3\theta^{3} + a_4\theta^{4} + a_5\theta^{5})/F$
$(8.1)\space\space\space T_1 = (b_{10} + b_{11}\theta + b_{12}\theta^{2} + b_{13}\theta^{3}b_{14}\theta^{4}+b_{15}\theta^5)/(2F)$
$(8.2)\space\space\space T_2 = (b_{20} + b_{21}\theta + b_{22}\theta^{2} + b_{23}\theta^{3}+b_{24}\theta^{4}+b_{25}\theta^5)/(2DF)$
$(8.3)\space\space\space T_3 = (b_{30} + b_{31}\theta + b_{32}\theta^{2} + b_{33}\theta^{3}+b_{34}\theta^{4}+b_{35}\theta^5)/(2F)$
$(8.4)\space\space\space T_4 = (b_{40} + b_{41}\theta + b_{42}\theta^{2} + b_{43}\theta^{3}+b_{44}\theta^{4}+b_{45}\theta^5)/(2DF)$

The values are given explicitly for the general polynomial $f(x) = x^5 + px^3 + qx^2 + rx + s$ in the Appendix (on microfiche) in terms of $p, q, r, s$."

The quotation above is an excerpt from *Dummit, D. S.*, [**Solving solvable quintics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2938681), Math. Comput. 57, No. 195, 387-401 (1991). [ZBL0729.12008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0729.12008).

It says that the appendix for those values ($b_{10},b_{11},b_{12},$etc..) is on the microfiche somewhere, but I couldn't find it. Later I figured out that the appendix was accidentally not added to the microfiche through *Dummit, D. S.*, [**Corrigenda: Solving solvable quintics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2153010), Math. Comput. 59, No. 199, 309 (1992). [ZBL0747.12002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0747.12002).

What do I do to find these values?

Comment: I've been seeking a solution to a quintic equation for many months.  I don't understand your question. Can you edit your question and give some reference to what prompted the question?